# ASP.NET iframe: place meta tag in the parent frame

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have a page with an iframe in which depending on my action inside the iframe, I need to put a meta tag on the parent of the iframe.  How can I do this in code behind.  What i have is like this but the meta tag is placed inside the iframe.

```
// code behind of the iframe where I created a meta tag and placed it on the page.
HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
meta.Name= "Keywords";
meta.Content = "some keywords i created based on the event of iframe.";
this.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
```

Unfortunately, the meta tag is placed inside the iframe, I want to put it on the parent of the iframe.

Comment: Is your Iframe set with **runat=server** ? Then you have **iframe1.Parent** available

Comment: no, the iframe is added dynamically via javascript.

Comment: @V4Vendetta: It's not available from the code behind of the iframe, only from the code behind of the containing page, and it's not a reference to the page, but a reference to the parent element of the iframe control.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access the parent page from the code behind of the page in the iframe. You have to use client script for that.

Adding meta tags with client script has limited usefulness, though. Setting the keywords using client script has for example no effect for SEO.

Comment: my meta tags is not for SEO purposes, so I am willing to accept any solutions, as long as I can add the meta tag based on the users choice of event inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for that

```
$('meta[name="keywords"]', window.parent.document).attr('content','some key words');
```